# Check if imgur URL is a link to an image or an album

Tags: php, imgur

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Adyg/php-imgur-api-client) PHP imgur API implementation. I need to be able to distinguish whether a given imgur ID is an image or an album, however, I see no way to do this with the above library.

For example, with the ID `arP2Otg` (from the URL `https://imgur.com/gallery/arP2Otg`), how would I be able to check if it's an image or an album? Otherwise, I'm unable to know which method of extraction I'm meant to use:

```
$album = $client->api('album')->album($albumId);
```

or

```
$image = $client->api('image')->image($imageId);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without using any library since their API is quite easy. Just append `.json` to the url and you'll get all the info about that particular link:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://imgur.com/gallery/arP2Otg.json');
$obj = json_decode($data);
var_dump($obj->data->image->is_album); // will output "bool(false)"
```

Head over [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/arP2Otg.json) to see all the information returned by their API.

Comment: I'd rather use the library I'm already using rather. Do you know how I could do that?

Answer (score -1):

Album URLs contain`/a/` and image URLs don't.

Then, you can use `strpos` (assuming your mysterious id is on `$theId`):

```
if (strpos($theId, '/a/') !== false) {
    $image = $client->api('image')->image($theId);
    // do things with $image
} else {
    $album = $client->api('album')->album($theId);
    // do things with $album
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is related to the question ;)
Theres just the "ID" which seems to be the part just after the '/a/'. To check for the '/a/' you'd need the whole url.